# Decile, Quintile, and Quartile from Class Rank and Class Size

Tags: excel

For a student I have the class rank of 58 (in cell A1), and the class size of 112 (in cell B1).  Am I able to write three Excel formulas that will calculate the decile, quintile, and quartile ranks for this student?

I found a few formulas similar to this:  =MATCH(A1,PERCENTILE(A$1:A$131,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1) but they work with ranking values in a range of data rows rather than with two specific numbers for a single record as represented in my question above.

Thank you,

Lindsay

Comment: The RANK function along with some simple maths should be able to do this. Can you provide sample data together with expected results?

Comment: I feel like this is a math question rather than Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 1st quartile rank is the best (highest) then try this formula for quartile rank

`=MAX(1,CEILING((1-A1/B1)*4,1))`

Do the same for quintile and decile, just replacing the 4 in the formula with 5 or 10

For your example I get 2 for quartile rank, 3 for quintile rank and 5 for decile rank

Comment: Thank you Barry.  This appears to work almost perfectly except that it's backwards.  The 4 should be a 1, the 3 should be a 2, the 2 should be a 3, and the 1 should be a 4.  I tried revising it to try and reverse it but haven't yet figured it out.

Comment: I just got it by using =MAX(1,CEILING((A1/B1)*4,1))

Comment: Thank you so much Barry.